# How to count ocurrences of different predicates for the same subject and object in SparQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf

In my RDF graph, subjects (Persons in this case) can "react" to something (an object, for example an article, any "creative thing"). There can be multiple different reactions for the same person and object, that is, a person can for example find an article "interesting", "thoughtful", "perfect", so there would be 3 triples, one for each reaction.

For each reaction type, i want to count the number of reactions for a given person and object. I've tried the following query, which doesn't work as expected, as it doesn't seem to count by predicate (for example if there's only one "reactInteresting" ocurrence and no "reactHappy", both counters will be equal to 1).

```
SELECT (COUNT(schema:reactInteresting) as ?countInteresting)
  (COUNT(schema:reactHappy) as ?countHappy)                                         
WHERE {                                                                       
  ?agentUri ?reaction ?object .

  FILTER(?reaction IN (schema:reactInteresting, schema:reactHappy))
}
GROUP BY ?agentUri
```

I've also tried using UNION, and the same problem occurs.

```
SELECT (COUNT(schema:reactInteresting) as ?countInteresting)
  (COUNT(schema:reactHappy) as ?countHappy)
WHERE {                                                                       
  {
    ?agentUri schema:reactInteresting ?rsc .
  } UNION {
    ?agentUri schema:reactHappy ?rsc .
  } .
}
```

*Note*: Using DISTINCT with the COUNT, or GROUP BY have no effect on the results

The sparql engine is rdflib (python). Is there a way to achieve this without writing a (complex) nested query ? Given that there'll be a lot of different reaction types ... Thank you.

Comment: not sure what exactly you'Re doing, but you have to count the bindings of variables, not a single predicate URI. Also, I don't get what exactly is given, you say person and object are given, but then you should set those URIs. Moreover, there will be only one reaction between the same subject and object, not as you said "there can be multiple". It's impossible, an RDF triples is unique as RDF is a **set** of triples.

Comment: `SELECT ?agentUri ?reaction (count(?object) as ?cnt)                                         
    WHERE { 
      VALUES ?reaction {schema:reactInteresting schema:reactHappy}
      ?agentUri ?reaction ?object .


    }
    GROUP BY ?agentUri ?reaction` will return the number of reactions per agent and reaction type.

Comment: @UninformedUser Thank you for your help, you're right i need to count the binding. I've updated the question, clarifying that part: there's one triple per reaction, only the predicate varies. So when a person finds an article "interesting" and "funny", there are 2 triples (with identical subject and object), only the predicate varies (schema:reactInteresting and schema:reactFunny). Thank you for the solution you proposed, will try it and give an update.

Comment: @UninformedUser Tried your elegant solution and it does exactly what i need, it's brilliant ! I cannot thank you enough for taking the time.